# FireBase iOS queryOrderedByChild not working

Tags: ios, firebase

I am getting results from the code below but they are not in the specified order.

```
Firebase *myRootRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com"];
Firebase *updates = [[myRootRef childByAppendingPath:@"data"] childByAppendingPath:@"Offences"];
[updates queryOrderedByChild:@"dateUpdated"];
[updates observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"VALUE: %@", snapshot.value);
 }];
```

The child `Offences` is a `JSON` array like this...

```
[ {
  "dateUpdated" : 20140915,
  "name" : "Bla bla bla"
}, {
  "dateUpdated" : 20140912,
  "name" : "Bla bla bla"
}, {
  "dateUpdated" : 20140914,
  "name" : "Bla bla bla"
} ]
```

I suspect it is the fact it is in an array that is causing the problem, any help appreciated.

Comment: Calling `queryOrderedByChild` **returns** a modified query, so you need to chain the mehthod calls: `[[updates queryOrderedByChild:@"dateUpdated"] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded...]`. See the example "Ordering using a child key" here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data

Comment: I thought I had tried that, thanks - If you put this as an answer I can accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `queryOrderedByChild` **returns** a modified query. So you need to chain the mehthod calls:

```
[[updates queryOrderedByChild:@"dateUpdated"] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded...]
```

See the example "Ordering using a child key" here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data